# Android - Async download an image and display it

Tags: java, android

This is the code, the image is indeed downloaded but the problem is that i cannot display it because of not beeing able to resolve method findViewById

```
public class ImageDownloader
    extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {

protected void onPreExecute(){
    //Setup is done here
}
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
    //this where i get the image using HttpURLConnection 
}
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... params){
    //Update a progress bar here, or ignore it, it's up to you
}
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap img){
    //here is the problem with findViewById beeing undefined
    ImageView image_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.remote_image);

    if(image_view!=null && img!=null){
        image_view.setImageBitmap(img);
    }
}
```

On my Main Activity i call the ImageDownloader inside OnCreate like this:

```
 ImageDownloader download = new ImageDownloader();
 download.execute("http://wanderingoak.net/bridge.png");
```

`

Comment: Is `remote_image` the id of your image view in your **current** layout?

Comment: Obviously asynctask doesn't have such method... Obviously you have to pass imageview reference to it or make your asynctask implementation inner non static class of the class which have such method... Looks like lack of java's basics (not connected with android at all)

Comment: yes it is the name of the ImageView located inside content_main.xml

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Comment: @Selvin how do i pass the imageview reference inside of an AsyncTask?

Comment: You need to add a constructor to `ImageDownloader` which takes an `Activity` as a parameter...or better yet, an `ImageView`.

Comment: Seriously, use an external image loading library to do this for you, it'll significantly reduce your development time for such trivial tasks

Comment: thank you for suggesting the library but right now im just doing some test project to see how things work

Comment: @cricket_007 I agree that third-party libraries are good for this, especially if development time is critical. At the same time, using an AsyncTask to do it yourself is a good learning exercise and not entirely trivial.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice this is exactly the reason i tried not to use any third party libraries, even for http requests. I do not plan to do the same thing on my next project since now i have seen what's under the hood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android developers page provides many useful examples: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

I assume You are doing right with handling multiple downloading images. But if so, then Your asyncTask should check if reference to imageView exists.
You should go in this direction:

```
public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {

        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

        public ImageDownloader(ImageView imageView) {
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //Setup is done here
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            //this where i get the image using HttpURLConnection
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... params) {
            //Update a progress bar here, or ignore it, it's up to you
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {

            if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
                final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageView != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then You call for example:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
        new ImageDownloader(iv).execute("http://wanderingoak.net/bridge.png");
    }
```

Comment: this surely works and helped me a lot. What if i want to display a Loader while the image is downloading?

Comment: @Akis_Tfs, Just use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), It's a lot easier to use and lets you do that easily.

Answer (score 3):

To access `findViewById` you need an actual view. You can only use that method in `Activity`, `Fragment`, or `View` classes.

Pass in the reference, and don't do things your classes are not supposed to do:

```
// add the constructor
public ImageDownloader(ImageView image) {
    mImage = image;
}
```

Then call the constructor:

```
ImageDownloader download = new ImageDownloader((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.remote_image));
```

The *clean* solution should additionally use a `WeakReference<ImageView>` instead of an `ImageView`, because keeping the reference in long running tasks can cause memory leaks.

Using an `AsyncTask` as a not static inner class will *not* prevent the same issue, since it will also keep a reference to the activity, causing said memory leak.

Comment: The OP must also be careful that the `ImageView` isn't destroyed before trying to set its image.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Wouldn't worst case just leak the activity? You're right, a `WeakReference` would be the way to go, but I did not want to overstrain the OP.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about the life cycle issues here. What happens if the `AsyncTask` starts, then the user navigates to another activity/fragment, and finally the `AsyncTask` finishes and sets the image of the `ImageView`? Will the reference in `ImageDownloader` be valid?

Comment: tried this and worked indeed but is this the proper way to do it?

Comment: @Akis_Tfs There could be many ways to do it depending on your situation, but I think in your case the imageview should be a property of the activity, no need to pass it to the asynctask

Comment: @Akis_Tfs You should additionally use a `WeakReference` as can be seen in deadfishs answer, since as you can see in the comments, doing it without one will also work, but may cause a memory leak

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your `imageview` as a field in your activity

Initialize it in on create

```
private ImageView image_view;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    image_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.remote_image);
    ImageDownloader download = new ImageDownloader();
    download.execute("http://wanderingoak.net/bridge.png");
}
```

your async task:

```
public class ImageDownloader
    extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        //Setup is done here
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        //this where i get the image using HttpURLConnection 
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... params){
        //Update a progress bar here, or ignore it, it's up to you
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap img){
        if(image_view!=null && img!=null){
            image_view.setImageBitmap(img);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should include the enclosing class declarations to make your answer more clear.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice like this?

Comment: Which class contains the `onCreate()`? And how does `ImageDownloader` get access to the `image_view`?

Comment: The async task should be part of the activity, then it can access that field of the activity

Comment: That's certainly one solution. Your answer can be improved by showing this explicitly.

Comment: @meda this will also cause a memory leak as discussed in my answers comments, since non static inner classes hold a reference to the enclosing one